# Why my CSS class don't work on edge && ie

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, angular7, microsoft-edge

I have angular7 application and i have wrote my own class, for my button. the code of the button and the class "btn-baya" is like the following code .

```
<a [routerLink]='["/eval-detail",evaluation.id]' class=" btn-baya">En savoir plus</a>

.btn-baya {
background-color: rgba(243, 116, 33) !important;
color: #ffffff !important;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

this code works on all browsers but not ie10 and edge !! any solutions please

Comment: probably it is not your issue, but `rgba()` shouldn't have 4 values instead of 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rgba` color expression needs 4 values. From it's name — "red", "green", "blue", "alpha". You only have three.

Either specify alpha:

```
rgba(243, 116, 33, 1)
```

Or use `rgb()`:

```
rgb(243, 116, 33)
```